# Ember not transitioning to profile after logging in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, ember.js

I am working on an Ember project with a Node backend.  I would like to have a user login/ signup on the client side, send an AJAX POST request to the server to check its authentication and then send back a thumbs up or a thumbs down accordingly.  If a thumbs up is returned I want to transition the user to their profile.  However, when the person submits the form, a successful POST request is sent but nothing happens as far as transitioning to another page.  Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Here is what my Route looks like:

```
// Username for the new user
    email: '',

    // Password for the new user
    password: '',
        actions: {

        manualLogin: function() {
          const email = this.get('email');
          const password = this.get('password');
          var temp = this;

          Ember.$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/api/login",
            data: { email: email, password: password }
          })
            .done(function(data) {
              console.log('transition to /user, ' + data);
              temp.transitionTo('user');
            })
            .fail(function(data) {
              console.log(data);
            });
          //this.transitionTo('user');

          return;
          }
        }
```

Here is my Router:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('explore', { path: '/' });
  this.route('user');
  this.route('login');
  this.route('signup');
});
```

And the code for the submit button with the login template:

```
<button class="button radius" type="submit" {{action 'manualLogin'}}>Login</button>
```

Comment: Curious, if you call `this.transitionTo('user') outside of the callback, does it work fine?

Comment: What about console? Do you see something there? What happens if you will call temp.transitionTo('/user') (with slash)?

Comment: If you are using ember-cli, you may want to use this library  https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth

Comment: That seems to be where this problem is stemming from I've figured out.  Because when I change the transitionTo to my 'signup' page for example for some reason it goes there just fine.  But my 'user' page is behind a protected route made from ember-simple-auth.  Is there any way that you know of to get ember-simple-auth to recognize when my node server has authenticated a session? @GennadyDogaev

Comment: You need an authenticator and an authorizer that are able to work with your server. There is some extensions for ember-simple-auth. I used this https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/master/packages/ember-simple-auth-oauth2 Read docs, do what they say and you will be fine